# TFS Query - How to query backlog by Board Column change date

Tags: tfs

I would like to query the current work item backlog in TFS (2017) to display stories/bugs that have been on a specific board column for 2 days or more. However, the 'Change Date' field in my query is indicative of ANY change to a specific work item (e.g., comment added to discussion, assignment/priority/story points updated...etc.  I thought this would be a great place to find help for my query.

Current fields in my TFS Query:

1. Area Path = /PathToArea
2. Board Column IN 'X','Y','Z'
3. Change Date  <= @Today -2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the field **"State Change Date"** to filter the result.

By default, Board Column is mapped to the state, that means when you move a work item to a specific Board Column, the sate will also be changed accordingly. So we can track that using **"State Change Date"**. See details [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/history-and-auditing#fields-that-support-history-auditing-and-revision-tracking)

See below example:

[image]

Comment: @T.Edelen Have you resolved your issue by above workaround?

Comment: This doesn't work if you don't map board columns to states 1-to-1. My project has fewer states on workitems than my team has columns, and we can't create additional states project wide.